# What happened to the baby in "An American Tail"?

Tags: plot-explanation, an-american-tail

Right at the beginning of *An American Trail* the whole family migrated to America. Mom cared for a baby the whole time.

Not sure, if it appears at the market, but afterwards you won't see the baby again.

Are there any references, what happened to it?

(I haven't seen the other parts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TV Tropes lists the baby, Yasha, under the appropriately-named trope "[What Happened To The Mouse?](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WhatHappenedToTheMouse/AnimatedFilms)", about minor characters whose stories are never wrapped up:

> The young baby of the Mousekewitz family, Yasha, drops out of the film about halfway through — particularly conspicuous in a story about accidental family separation. **She does appear in the sequels, however.**

The most likely explanation - as disappointing as it is - is that the animators simply forgot about her due to her lack of prominence in the main plot.